# Is there a way to decompile the java class

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)
>   [How do I “decompile” Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

Any tool can decompile the class back to java source? Like the reflector in C#?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler

Comment: These are previous questions about this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383022/what-is-the-best-software-to-decompile-a-java-class-file

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378669/how-to-decompile-java

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151696/decompile-compiled-java-file-with-proprietary-headers

Comment: If only there were some way to find answers that already exist. Some means of searching or something.

Answer (score 1):

See [How do I "decompile" Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files)

About JAD: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/decompile-class-file-java-decompiler-class-java-class.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use javap command for that

```
javap classname
```

to get the full code i guess there are a lot of java decompilers available on net for free..

Answer (score 0):

A Java class can be decompiled by using a decompiler which takes a `.class` files as input and gives its Java source code as output.

---

Refer these questions on stackoverflow for more details.

[How do I “decompile” Java class files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272535/how-do-i-decompile-java-class-files) *(Using external tools)*
[How to Decompile Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378669/how-to-decompile-java) *(using* `javap` *command that is available with JDK)*

---

Also See
[What is the best software to decompile a java class file ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383022/what-is-the-best-software-to-decompile-a-java-class-file)
[Where can I find a Java decompiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671394/where-can-i-find-a-java-decompiler)
[Decompile compiled Java file with proprietary headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4151696/decompile-compiled-java-file-with-proprietary-headers)